# svg tutorials that show how to do mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, svg

a. i have a huge SVG file
2. i have objects in the SVG file that look like this:

```
<path 
     style="fill:#f7d3aa;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 923.03026,37.975518 C 922.57184,38.995849 921.76084,41.697403 921.76084,44.352463 C 921.76084,47.130382 919.49185,46.324054 921.76084,48.603761 C 922.79254,49.640303 925.33008,47.328371 926.83847,47.328371 C 928.64472,47.328371 928.45237,51.223763 930.22354,51.579668 C 932.37666,52.012321 934.08737,52.522241 936.14743,52.004798 C 938.36058,51.448909 939.8978,50.502312 942.49447,51.154539 C 943.89657,51.506717 946.44388,48.461872 947.14893,47.753502 C 949.30188,45.590391 946.8075,50.401063 946.7258,50.729408 C 946.0737,53.350095 949.5805,52.429926 951.38029,52.429926 C 954.13433,52.429926 955.03028,50.940072 955.61163,48.603761 C 955.78273,47.916101 952.46128,44.82413 952.22655,44.352463 C 951.88695,43.670052 955.05553,42.433288 956.45789,41.376556 C 959.00459,39.457537 958.11054,38.360573 956.88104,37.125259 C 955.02965,35.26515 952.06131,38.141523 950.95714,39.250906 C 949.94504,40.267774 946.8031,41.463423 945.45641,41.801685 C 943.67466,42.24922 941.73037,44.09862 940.37878,44.777594 C 938.61378,45.664254 936.79892,46.420756 934.87803,46.903242 C 933.25123,47.311861 930.50953,44.639791 929.80042,43.927334 C 928.30508,42.424964 926.15309,43.238719 924.7228,41.801685 C 923.48412,40.557171 928.92137,37.975518 923.03026,37.975518 z"
     id="path2688" />
```

3. as you can see it is not a regular svg shape. the coordinates are manually defined and this makes the problem trickier.
4. i need it so that when the user puts his mouse over any one of these objects for a tooltip to pop up with customized text

so far i have not been able to find a solution for this complex problem.

do you know how to do it?

Comment: You asked at least two questions before this one today, both of which you appear to have deleted (along with the answers people gave you). Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
<path style="fill:#f7d3aa;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 923.03026,37.975518 C 922.57184,38.995849 921.76084,41.697403 921.76084,44.352463 C 921.76084,47.130382 919.49185,46.324054 921.76084,48.603761 C 922.79254,49.640303 925.33008,47.328371 926.83847,47.328371 C 928.64472,47.328371 928.45237,51.223763 930.22354,51.579668 C 932.37666,52.012321 934.08737,52.522241 936.14743,52.004798 C 938.36058,51.448909 939.8978,50.502312 942.49447,51.154539 C 943.89657,51.506717 946.44388,48.461872 947.14893,47.753502 C 949.30188,45.590391 946.8075,50.401063 946.7258,50.729408 C 946.0737,53.350095 949.5805,52.429926 951.38029,52.429926 C 954.13433,52.429926 955.03028,50.940072 955.61163,48.603761 C 955.78273,47.916101 952.46128,44.82413 952.22655,44.352463 C 951.88695,43.670052 955.05553,42.433288 956.45789,41.376556 C 959.00459,39.457537 958.11054,38.360573 956.88104,37.125259 C 955.02965,35.26515 952.06131,38.141523 950.95714,39.250906 C 949.94504,40.267774 946.8031,41.463423 945.45641,41.801685 C 943.67466,42.24922 941.73037,44.09862 940.37878,44.777594 C 938.61378,45.664254 936.79892,46.420756 934.87803,46.903242 C 933.25123,47.311861 930.50953,44.639791 929.80042,43.927334 C 928.30508,42.424964 926.15309,43.238719 924.7228,41.801685 C 923.48412,40.557171 928.92137,37.975518 923.03026,37.975518 z"
     id="path2688" >
 <title>Something you want in a tooltip</title>
</path>
```

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/struct.html#TitleElement):

> User agents may, however, for example,
>   display the 'title' element as a
>   tooltip, as the pointing device moves
>   over particular elements

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after about 30 questions, NO ONE was able to answer this except for you

Comment: where can i send your check/??

Comment: would you like a tax receipt?